# How to import an Excel document in AzureDevOps Dashboard's widget

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard, excel-import

For inclusive reporting purpose - I need to get the incident details from Service now and show it in a widget on AzureDevOps Dashboard, along with other development widgets on the same dashboard.

I am planning to export the data from Service now in an excel and upload that in a dashboard widget as I am not sure if my this existing dashboard can directly connect to service now Dashboard of mine.

I have tried looking into different kind of widgets but none gave me an option to import data from excel document or a url option to get the data from Service now dashboard.

Can anyone help me here?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Iframe Dashboard Widget support a url option to display web content. You can get it from https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/ and it is free. Because of web security and different platforms, it can’t display the data from Service now dashboard but can redirect to Service now dashboard through user authentication.

And there is no widget support to import data from excel document, sorry.

I think if you can export the data from Service now in an excel, then you can insert the excel in Wiki which you can share the data across the team. Although when the data update, you should upload excel again.

I hope all of these can help you, have a good day.